# TinyMCE: disable html edit button

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, tinymce

Is there a way in TinyMCE to disable the "edit html" button? I'm overwhelmed by the [config options](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration) and can't seem to find it. I noticed users can use that to place javascript in their field which I do not want.  By the way I am using this gem - https://github.com/spohlenz/tinymce-rails

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `theme_advanced_disable: "code"` when you initialise the tinymce object.

EDIT - didn't see you were using the rails version, sorry. This will remove the button in plain javascript.

Comment: Both you and Ben are correct, this worked, thanks to both I will +1 both.  I believe GarethL had the theme_advanced_disable code posted a few seconds earlier thus the acceptance of this answer.

Answer (score 2):

You might try:

```
HtmlEditorConfig::get('cms')->removeButtons('advcode');
```

or

```
theme_advanced_disable: "code"
```

I've made a fiddle here: http://fiddle.tinymce.com/cmcaab

If you're trying to have it set by the gem rather than just writing the javascript, you just need to edit the `config/tinymce.yml` file. So the `yml` file should have a line that says

```
theme_advanced_disable: code
```

OR (from README on that gem)

> Custom options can be passed to tinymce to override the global options
>   specified in config/tinymce.yml:

So I think you can just add a `:theme_advanced_disable => ["code"]` when calling the timeMCE (though I'm not 100% sure that's the correct syntax):

```
<%= tinymce :theme => "simple", :theme_advanced_disable => ["code"], :plugins => ["inlinepopups", "paste"] %>
```

You can read more about this [here](http://archive.ssbits.com/customising-the-wysywig-editor-in-v2-3-2-tinymce/):

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean the "edit html source" button? You could just not put it in the toolbar, under the `theme_advanced_buttons` options all you have to do is omit it.

The button is called `code`